Will a LPF filter on the transmitter prevent CW key clicks?
Reading about key clicks, it would seem that they are primarily caused by the fact that the square wave of turning the key on and off must, by definition, have higher frequency harmonics, which sound like clicks.
If my transmitter's power amplifier has a good LPF, which eliminates harmonics of the main carrier (7 MHz), won't it also eliminate clicks?

To extend on Dave's excellent point.
Take this (simplified) block diagram of the minimum CW transmitter:

I'll just give names like $m(t)$, $s(t)$ and $c(t)$ to signals in your CW transmitter, so that we can talk about it easier:
You have an oscillator at your RF frequency (say, your $f_c=7\text{ MHz}$), which generates a carrier signal $c(t)$. The "$(t)$" simply says "this is a signal, which varies with time. In the case of carriers, the way they vary with time is simple: they are some cosine (or sine wave, doesn't really matter, just a question of when you start looking) wave of the given frequency, we could as well directly write that $c(t) = \cos(2\pi f_c \cdot t)$, and have a nice mathematical model.
So, we use that oscillator and use it in a mixer to mix the carrier $c(t)$ with the message signal $m(t)$. What that does is pretty simple: it shifts the message signal in frequency both up and down by the carrier's frequency $f$. OK, that's probably not surprising to you! But, that "shifting in frequency", it just means that you literally take the spectrum of $m(t)$ as it is, and, well, you shift it up to $+f_c$ and down to $-f_c$ (and because the spectrum of your real-valued is symmetrical, the resulting spectrum is symmetrical to zero frequency).
Thus, if there's any emissions outside of what we want, either our mixer isn't working as intended, or more likely in this case, the spectrum of $m(t)$ already contains these unwanted frequency components!
Let's quickly look at the spectrum of a rectangular pulse like pressing and releasing the key would ideally produce. A quick trip to wikipedia yields a table of correspondences between time-domain signals and their frequency domain form, and especially:

$\operatorname*{rect}(ax)$ ○—● $\frac{1}{\lvert a\rvert} \operatorname*{sinc}\left(\frac{\xi}{a}\right)$

Gotta take that apart. $\operatorname*{rect}$ is for "rectangular pulse"; it is 1 when its argument, $ax$ is between -0.5 and +0.5, and it has value 0 everywhere else (so, the pulse is of length 1 and centered around t=0). The $ax$ is our "time variable" here; the larger $a$, the shorter the pulse is (because, for example, if we set $a=2$, then the argument becomes 0.5 already for $x=0.25$, whereas if we set it to $a=1/2$, then we get that the argument $ax$ becomes 0.5 only at the point that $x$ has reached 1). Anyway, because we are in the best of senses, too lazy to care about stupid factors, we just set $a=1$ and replace $x$ with $t$, so that it fits our idea of what the time variable is called. So, there we go,
$$m(t) = \operatorname*{rect}(ax) \overset{a=1, x=t}{=} \operatorname*{rect}(t).$$
Ok, our table entry tells us that the frequency-domain version of $m(t)$, which we call $M(f)$, now becomes
$$M(f) = \frac{1}{\lvert a\rvert} \operatorname*{sinc}\left(\frac{f}{a}\right) = \operatorname*{sinc}(f),$$
because $a$ was 1, so the absolute value of $a$ is also 1, and you really don't need to write down multiplications with and divisions by 1.
That's awfully nice, but what the heck is $\operatorname*{sinc}$?
Well, it's $\operatorname*{sinc}(f) = \frac{\sin(\pi  f)}{\pi f}$; and when you plot it, it looks like this:

I just stopped plotting at $f=-10$ and $f=+10$; the spectrum just continues forever, even if it's getting "weaker" the further you get from the zero frequency.
Takeaways:

The spectrum of a rectangular pulse is "kind of funny", in that it has sidelobes for all frequencies
When we make the pulse shorter (set $a$ to a value larger than 1), then our spectrum becomes wider (that's also something familiar to hams, the faster you key, the wider your transmission necessarily becomes). Conversely, the slower the rectangle, the more the sinc becomes "concentrated" around zero frequency.
To get rid of the sidelobes, we need to "modify" $m(t)$ before it goes into the mixer.

We call that process of shaping the pulses of the message signal pulse shaping in communications engineering. Plenty of ways you can do that:
For example you can make sure the current coming out of your key system is equally strong (in either direction) when the key is high as when it's low,  by having the key connect a resistor to ground when closed. That means the "key side" of the resistor is at high potential when the key is open, and at low when it's closed. Now, because you can put much more current through a closed key than through a resistor, you'd connect that to a simple buffer (think: two transistors in a push-pull configuration, or, much simpler, a logic gate / logic buffer). Then, you take that output, and feed it through an RC filter: when high, you charge the capacitor at limited speed (defined by the R), and when low, you discharge it at limited speed. By choosing R and C, you can select the edge steepness. That gives your former rectangle a kind of rounded shape, and thus reduces the bandwidth.
That's probably pretty much the minimum you would want to do for any real-world key system, anyways: We know from painful practice that keys bounce, i.e. the key doesn't go from "off" to "on" (or vice versa) cleanly in swoop fell, no, it bounces around between off and on for a few milliseconds. Imagine that! Now instead of these nice and wide rectangles (with nice and narrow sinc shape), you get the spectrum of tiny quasi-rectangular pulses that happen with an $a$ of maybe $a= \frac{1}{100\text{ µs}}$, and in effect, you get a main sinc lobe that is 10 kHz wide! Uff!
Now, high-quality keys certainly reduce that button bounce problem, but they can't eliminate it. An inherent or explicit limiting of message signal bandwidth is something you will roughly always find in any communication system. This also goes for automatic/iambic keys, where pressing the key to one side automatically produces dits, and to the other it produces dah's. Typically, you'd build something like that with a three-position switch of sorts ("connecting A to ground", "connecting none to ground, "connecting B to ground", for example), and a simple microcontroller (really, a good project to do your first microcontroller steps) that takes two inputs, checks whether one is pulled to ground and starts emitting short or long pulses. You'd filter the output with an RC filter.

No, the key clicks, just like any form of AM, are carried in sidebands that are close to the carrier frequency. The type of LPF you're talking about will have no effect on them.
To eliminate key clicks, you need to modify the baseband signal before it's applied to the transmitter — i.e., do some shaping of the square wave itself.
